# How To Combine 2 COUNTUNIQUEIFS - If This AND That

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have three columns; Customer Name, Active License, Account Connected -

| Customer Name | Active License | Account Connected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Yes | Yes |
| Barry | Yes | No |
| Alex | No | No |
| Claire | No | No |
| Alex | No | No |
| Deborah | No | No |

I am using this formula to count the number of unique customers that have at least 1 active license: `=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes")` and the same to count the number of customers with at least 1 account connected. `=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,C2:C,"Yes")`

How can I combine the two formulas to count the number of unique customers who have at least one active license **AND** at least one account connected. And how can I do it in the negative; counting the number of unique customers who have at least one active license but ***don't have** any connected accounts.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Obviously - ```=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes",C2:C,"Yes")``` and ```=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes",C2:C,"No")```

Answer (score 0):

Use "basic" is correct in his comment to your original post that the following will give you the unique count of "Yes/Yes":

`=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes",C2:C,"Yes")`

However, his second suggestion will not produce the "Yes... without *any* second Yes'es." This is because some users with a "Yes/Yes" may also have entries with "Yes/No"; but they should not be counted since they *do* have at least one "Yes/Yes".

Instead, you'd use the count of all "Yes/?" and subtract those with any "Yes/Yes":

`=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes") - COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes",C2:C,"Yes")`

If you already have a cell containing the "Yes/Yes" count somewhere (say, D2), you can just sub that into the formula:

`=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A,B2:B,"Yes") - D2`

And if you have *both* the "Yes/?" count in a cell (say, C2) *and* the "Yes/Yes" count in a cell (say, D2), you can reduce to just the cell references:

`=C2 - D2`

This seems like it was more of a logic question than a Sheets question, per se. But there's my take on it.